# Prisma with typescript throw Invalid invocation

Tags: next.js, types, prisma

I use nextjs 13 with ts to [pass the data from a client component to a API route. In the client component, I just send the email required and pass the data to backend via fetch.

In the backend, I created the type of the body that comes from the fromtend, and I assigned to a constant called `res`;
After I used prisma to create a record. However, if I log the res variable to the console I get the proper data from the frontend. But the prisma function does not wants to execute.

```
import { prisma } from "@/app/db/PrismaClient";
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";


type TBodyRequest = {
    dateRequired: string,
    fullName: string,
    service: string,
    phoneNumber: string,
    email: string,
    details: string,
    numberOfVechicles: string
}



export const POST = async (request: Request) => {
        
    try {
        const res: TBodyRequest = await request.json();
        

        console.log('RES---------------------', res);
        
        // Add the recors in the database
        const responseFromDB = await prisma.clientQuote.create({
            data: {
                dateTimeNeeded: res.dateRequired,
                nameClient: res.fullName,
                numberOfVechicles: +res.numberOfVechicles,
                serviceRequired: res.service,
                phoneNumber: res.phoneNumber,
                clientEmail: res.email,
                detailsOfQuote: res.details
            }});
        
        
        return NextResponse.json({responseFromDB});
    } 
    
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        
    }
}
```

And the errors saying that
[image]

Comment: it looks like you're trying to get the post data from the response instead of the request